# How to calculate the symbolic inverse matrix on cluster with multiple nodes?

Tags: parallelization

I'm trying next commands for Mathematica 11.2.0:

```
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[2]
m1 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {4, 4}];
Parallelize[inv = Inverse[m1], Kernels[]]
sourceM1
m1
inverse
inv
```

And its commands issue next output:

```
{KernelObject[49,local],KernelObject[50,local]}
Parallelize[inv=Inverse[m1],{KernelObject[49,local],KernelObject[50,local]}]
sourceM1
{{7,-6,2,-9},{-2,-6,3,-4},{9,10,10,-10},{6,2,10,10}}
inverse
inv
```

Why I see "inv" string instead inversion result? How get result of expression `inv=Inverse[m1]`?

If I remove second argument `Kernels[]` from `Parallelize`, then it work fine, but how I can evaluate symbolic matrix inversion on cluster with gridMathematica without explicit kernels specification? How can I calculate the inverse matrix on cluster with multiple nodes?

Comment: `Parallelize` doesn't have two arguments. Since you are calling the function with the wrong number of arguments it will not do anything at all. If you remove the second argument then it will return your inverse matrix.

Comment: `Inverse` can't be automatically parallelized. Only those operations can that *explicitly* perform multiple calculations, such as Table, Map, Outer, or even  `{calc1, calc2, calc3}`. If you can't trivially break the computation down to separately evaluatable Mathematica expressions, then it can't be auto-parallelized.